# regex - boundary characters (^ and $) versus escaped characters (\A and \Z)

Tags: regex, pcre

What are the differences between,

```
\A  Match at only beginning of string
\Z  Match at only end of string (or before newline at the end)

^   Match the beginning of the line
$   Match the end of the line (or before newline at the end)
```

Comment: In what language? I see no mentioning of `\A` or `\Z` in the `re_format(7)` manual.

Comment: You're right of course. My initial doubt was in Python but it applies to any language with a module implementing Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (though Python .re doesn't completely implement it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the perl documentation (I can't see them in the standard regex syntax):

> The "\A" and "\Z" are just like "^" and "$", except that they won't match multiple times when the "/m" modifier is used, while "^" and "$" will match at every internal line boundary.

You should be adding a perl tag if this is related just to Perl (or those languages or libraries using PCRE, Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

`\A` always matches the start of a string, and never matches after a line break, while many dialects have the possibility to make `^` match the beginning of a line as well.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html (look for 'Anchors').